# Apache not reading htacces file

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

Running Debian 5.0 and a default install of apache my htaccess files are not being read and I am out of ideas. Can any one give me a trouble shooting check list?

Answer (score 4):

`AllowOverride` controls the use (or not) of `.htaccess` files.

Review what your `AllowOverride` configuration is (a setting of `None` will prevent the reading of `.htaccess` files completely), and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I checked this not luck.

Comment: What's it set to?

Comment: After some digging I found in etc/apache2/sites-available/default that AllowOverride was set to none. So I fixed that ty ;) Do you know if there are any special rules for .htaccess files in sym linked folders?

Comment: Should work just fine, as long as you've got your `Options` for the location set to `FollowSymLinks`.